# RAID 5 Install on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, raid

Environment: Ubuntu Server 12.04, tried installing from bootable flash drive.
Got the following error: `No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu.`

I'm trying to set up a personal file server with software RAID 5. I just got three hard drives for this, but haven't found any solid documentation. I'm unsure what the basic way to partition my hard drives is. Can someone upload a screenshot of their "partition disks" screen so that I can compare with mine (attached)?

I tired to upload an image, but it said that I need reputation 10+ to post an image...

Should I set the bootable flag? Do I need a /home partition? A /boot partition? Should I "Use [my partition] as: Ext4 journaling file system"? Or make that field "physical volume for RAID"?

I am an engineer, but I have only a cursory knowledge of `all-things-linux`. If you know of any good learning resources I'd be happy to hear about those too (that way I don't have to blindly follow deprecated tutorials online).

Thank you,

References I've looked into:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID
- https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/advanced-installation.html
- http://forevergeeks.com/setup-ubuntu-server-with-raid-5/

Comment: So it turns out that the error is pretty relevant.  I selected my raid and then made it ext4 and mount to root /.  I still can't post the screenshot that solved it, but here is a text summary of my "Partition disks" menu:

RAID5 device #0 2.0TB software RAID device
  #1  2.0TB  f **ext4  /**
      512B unusable
SCSI3 (my first hard drive)
  #1 primary B K raid
  #3 primary F ext4 /boot
  FREE SPACE
  #5 logical  F swap  swap
SCSI3 (my 2nd hard drive)
  #1 primary  B K raid
SCSI4 (my 3rd hard drive)
  #1 primary B K raid

Hope it helps

Comment: uugh, had to put my answer in my own comment because i have no reputation and cannot answer my own question, but i hope it helps regardless

Comment: I upvoted your question, so you should have enough rep to answer and post images now.

Answer (score 1):

**Posting for Tarabyte**

So it turns out that the error
is pretty relevant. I selected
my raid and then made it
ext4 and mount to root /. I
still can't post the
screenshot that solved it, but here is a text summary of my
"Partition disks" menu:
RAID5 device #0 2.0TB
software RAID device #1
2.0TB f ext4 / 512B unusable SCSI3 (my first hard drive)

## 1 primary B K raid #3

primary F ext4 /boot FREE
SPACE #5 logical F swap
swap SCSI3 (my 2nd hard
drive) #1 primary B K raid SCSI4 (my 3rd hard drive) #1
primary B K raid Hope it
helps –tarabyte

Comment: Justt repost when you have enough rep. and I'll remove mine. (If you want to do it that way. It's your answer.)